# Why is an object I can edit in the front end not available in data loader?

Tags: data-loader

In this case the object in question is the service cloud standard object VoiceCall.

As the title says, I can edit records individually in the front end, but am not able to update them programmatically at all.

The object is not available in data loader.

When I try to update with anonymous apex I get this error:

COMPILE ERROR: DML operation Update not allowed on List

Edit: some additional info -

When I try to updated with salesforce inspector I get a similar error:
CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: entity type cannot be updated

The object in question is VoiceCall, which does support update() per the [soap api documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_voicecall.htm)

All the relevant permissions/licenses that I am aware of have been assigned, as evidenced by the fact that I can update this object via the front end.

It seems like there might be some setting on this object preventing programmatic updates, but I don't know what that might be.

Comment: For the dataloader comment, couple of initial thoughts - have you checked show all objects? What's the api version of your installed dataloader?

Comment: Yes, show all objects is checked. Version is 54.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to update via the rest api using the method outlined in this blog post:
https://anothersalesforceblog.com/2019/10/04/updating-datedconversionrate-rest-api/

Some answers on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/salesforce/comments/194quqz/why_cant_i_perform_any_programmatic_update_apex/) suggest that this limitation is because the object is stored in another platform or has an active connection to an underlying service, though I couldn't find any mention of this in any salesforce documentation.